# Adding users to the Global Address List (GAL) through the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: azure, outlook, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

Most of the posts I've read online about this are about a year old, or don't answer my question specifically. I know through the graph API you can view contacts and users, and you can add contacts and users, but when I've viewed the contacts and users through the graph API, they don't match what's in my global address list exactly. So I believe that they're not the same thing.

Also, a lot of the posts I've read asking questions similar to this have said adding users to the Global Address List is not supported through the Graph API and must be done programmatically through powershell or something like that. These answers though were posted around a year and a half ago. So I'm wondering if this still isn't possible through the graph API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At present, it is not possible to add the users to Global Address List. We are only to add the person contacts to the root Contacts folder or to the contacts endpoint of another contact folder( refer [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_contacts)).

You can try to submit the feedback from [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/) if you want the Microsoft Graph to support this feature.

Answer (score 3):

So firstly I'd like to understand why you indicate that the Global Address List is different from what you can get back from Graph API.  As far as I know these should be identical, so please indicate where you are seeing differences.  Also Azure AD PowerShell v2 calls through Graph.

As for updating the global address list, this is mostly possible through Graph API. If you are trying to add new users to your directory, you can POST on http://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users.  Please see https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/users and https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_users. There are also PowerShell cmdlets for this.  If you are trying to add organizational contacts, currently this is not supported through Graph API or through Azure AD PowerShell. Organizational contacts may be queried (currently only available in preview by doing GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/contacts), but adding org contact is only possible through creation in on-premises AD and synchronization though AD Connect OR via Exchange experiences (like Office portals or Exchange PowerShell).
Personal contacts may also be fetched and added through GET and POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/contacts respectively.

Hope this helps,

Comment: Awesome Dan, this is actually the best solution since Microsoft Graph supports it now. Can't wait until it gets into GA, is there any estimate?

Comment: Users is already GA. Are you asking about when org contacts are available in GA (v1.0)?

Comment: Yeah, I meant org contacts.